# Internal Microphone is suddenly no longer detected

Tags: kubuntu, pulseaudio, microphone

This is concerned with Ubuntu 20.04, and the same version with the KDE desktop environment

When I first installed Kubuntu, the internal microphone was detected and worked normally. To confirm that nothing has went wrong with it, I just booted into LiveUSBs using both Ubuntu and Kubuntu, and the microphone is still working normally.

However, for some unknown reason, my internal microphone is no longer detected on my current installation. The KDE audio settings show the notice that there is "No Recording Devices Available".

["No Recording Devices Available"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3lqM.jpg)

I have used PulseAudio Volume Control, and even after unlocking the channels and playing around with the levels on the Input Devices Tab, I was not able to get it to work. After a reboot, the modifications I have made in this tab will be reset. The microphone is still undetected.

[PulseAudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHk2X.jpg)

[Output of lspci](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrDsQ.jpg)

May I know what you would recommend me to do? Please let me know if you need more outputs from me.

Comment: Some built-in webcams and microphones can be switched on and off with a Fn key, and on some machines it is the same key.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for replying. My machine is a Chromebook, so I am very confident I have not accidentally pressed a hotkey for disabling the microphone or the webcam. I have checked my list of hotkeys, and none of them correspond to disabling either device.

Comment: I just tried putting in this command:
`pacmd list-sources | egrep "name:|device.product.name"`

The output is as follows. There isn't any input device present!

`name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor>
                device.product.name = "Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller"`

Answer (score 13):

Sorry if that was ridiculous. I managed to solve it. It was driving me mad for hours.

The culprit was the Audio Profiles as I was trying to get the internal microphone to work instead of the external one, but that was not possible. I was not aware of what the Audio Profiles did at that time. Now I do.

I apparently had the Audio Profile set to output. This explains why no microphone was detected.

Go to `Audio Volume Settings > Advanced Tab`. The correct setting was "Analog Stereo Duplex". If you choose "Analog Stereo Ouptut", only the speaker will work, and the microphone will be disabled. If you choose "Analog stereo input", then the microphone will be enabled and the speakers will be disabled.

Comment: I was going crazy for the same reason! thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the fix - I had the exact same issue here in KDE Neon 5.20.

Comment: Holy cow.....don't know how the setting got changed....it was so annoying. 
Thank you!